# boot.elf not found - Smash Stack Wii

Tags: nintendo-wii, wii-u, super-smash-bros-brawl, homebrew

I have a 2GB SD card and I wanted to install the Homebrew Channel on the Wii so I did the Smash Stack method (private folder and boot.elf) and it says "boot.elf not found (-1)". I checked the SD Card compatibility list and I found my SD Card. I used this same SD Card on vWii (Wii U) and it worked on there but not my Wii. How do I fix this?

Comment: Is your card formatted correctly? Did you put the files in the right place?

Comment: @Thebluefish I formatted my SD Card to be FAT32 and every file is at the right place. I'll just try LetterBomb.